# Rest web service JSON request body with "truee" as boolean true value

Tags: java, rest

In a REST web service, the POST JSON body is like this:

```
{
    "printRequest" : {
        "printName" : "XYZ",
        "enable" : "truee",
        "printerDescription" : "anyString",
        "connectionString" : "YYYY",
        "ABC" : "XXX"
    }
}
```

Here attribute `enable` is of boolean type, but with extra "e" in "true". How do I deserialize it as plain Java boolean?

Comment: It is not necessary to use double quotes for boolean values and no more e at the end of true. Please see [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Hey Fernando, Thanks for ur comment. But, this is one of the validation issue whether we pass using double quoted or without, with an extra e, behaves the same i.e.,  It reads as true only.Ideally the same value should be sit in respective object variable.

Comment: I think the easiest way to fix is change the implementation on the client side.

Comment: Just a suggestion, what about pass a number instead of it? like 0 or 1. Where 0 means false and 1 true and validate it on server side.

Comment: fernando karpinski:- 0 or 1 works, But when we pass "turee" it is treated as "true", But we can't prevent QA team or user to pass this wrong value and I don't have any client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://json.org/) supports *real* booleans:

```
true
false
```

Note that there are *not quotes*. `"true"` is not a JSON boolean but a JSON string.

Do yourself a favour and fix the client to send this:

```
{
    "printRequest": {
        "printName": "XYZ",
        "enable": true,
        "printerDescription": "anyString",
        "connectionString": "YYYY",
        "ABC": "XXX"
    }
}
```